# How to use UPDATE in MySQL with string containing escape characters

Tags: mysql

please look here:

```
    UPDATE cars_tbl 
SET description = '{\rtf1'
WHERE (ID=1)
```

Description field is "blob", where my RTF document is to be stored.

When I check updated data I always find

```
{
tf1
```

\r simply disapears. I tried to find solution on the web, but no success. My rtf files are corrupted on many places, because the escape characters used in the string are substituted. How to suppress this substitution and update field with string as is?

Thanx for advice

Lyborko

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backslash is an escape character, so to keep it you need a double backslash:

```
UPDATE cars_tbl 
SET description = '{\\rtf1'
WHERE (ID=1)
```

As an aside `\r` is a carriage return.. and it hasn't disappeared in your data; it is responsible for `tf1` appearing on the line below the `{`.

Comment: so you mean, I when I have formatted RTF string, I have to replace one slash to two slash everywhere? Is this the only one method to do this??? Because RTF is full of it.

Comment: I'm surprised you have to do this, if you parse the RTF properly into a string and then bind it in using PDO or mysqli, it should work as is.

Comment: > sadly it is true. I hard coded the replacing of slash to double slash and it works... but it is nasty thing...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a more generic approach

use of **QUOTE()** in mysql

MySQL QUOTE() produces a string which is a properly escaped data value in an SQL statement, out of an user supplied string as argument.

The function achieve this by enclosing the string with single quotes, and by preceding each single quote, backslash, ASCII NUL and control-Z with a backslash.

**example**

`UPDATE cars_tbl 
SET description = QUOTE('{\rtf1')
WHERE (ID=1)`

**UPDATE**

to escape your RTF you can also just use **REPLACE** this way all your `\` will become `\\`

**Example**

`UPDATE cars_tbl 
SET description = REPLACE('{\rtf1', '\', '\\')
WHERE (ID=1)`

Comment: No, it does not work... it adds ' ' characters on the both ends of string, and uses escape chars anyway....

Comment: Yes you are right I didn't get what you wanted. Look at my update.

Comment: william, the syntax is somehow incorrect...: "....server version for the right syntax to use near '\\'  ". Thanx anyway... I replaced slash in the RTF string in the application...